# Is it possible to pass in ssl-client-cert for a kubernetes ingress

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, client-certificate

I have this setup for my ingress in kubernetes

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "namespace/secret"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "optional"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
```

This will send the verified certificate on to my upstream in the header `ssl-client-cert`, if it is validated correctly, but is it possible for an attacker here, to not provide a client certificate, and just set the `ssl-client-cert` to a certificate of their choosing? I have made a small test, and it doesn't look like it is possible, but i can't find anything about this as well in the docs. I know that the ingress uses `nginx`, and that default configuration for ([`proxy-pass-headers` is `true`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_headers)).

Can they just override the certificate? Can anyone provide me with some links to the documentation that tells me that it isn't possible or something of the like. I have read through the [annotations documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#client-certificate-authentication) without it telling me this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the bare basic of client certificates validation . No matter what application it is with validation using client certificates, there is always a chain of trust in the certificate which needs to be verified (root ca or intermediate root ca). And usually client certificates are issued by a ca to those who can use them, so the ca can also revoke them. Only if a threat actor is able to comprise the ca then he can issue the certs himself. So you can't also provide any certificate you like.

Comment: I know the chain trust. What I am asking for is if I am able to, as a caller, to set `ssl-client-verify` when sending in a request on the ingress, and it just passes along the header, or is it a reserved header in the nginx ingress that can't be passed upstream?